# SyntaxError: Expected "," or "}" but "ا" found. When compiling Arabic translations

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-translate

### Are there any known issues with compiling Arabic translations in `setTranslations(lang, translations)` method?

ngx-translate/core: 12.0.0
Angular: 10.0.8

#### Issue / support needed

Site has 6 different translation (de, en, es, it, fr, ar) languages(JSONs) loaded via HttpClient for ngx-translate library (great library btw) to use.  Objects storing translations have the same structure (of course different translations values) and are all gettable (displayed with TranslateService.getTranslations() method).

```
changeLocale(locale: 'de' | 'en' | 'it' | 'es' | 'fr' | 'ar'): void {
        this.identityService.changeLocale(locale).subscribe({
            next: () => {
                this.translate.getTranslation(locale).subscribe((translations) =>{
                    console.log(locale, translations) // Logs locale and object with translations
                    try{
                        this.translate.setTranslation(locale, translations) // sets translations to given locale
                        console.log("Set translation!")
                        this.translate.use(locale)
                        console.log("Used translation!")
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.error(e)
                    }

                })
            },
            error: (error) => this.messageService.processError(error)
        });
}
```

Problems occur when on line `this.translate.setTranslations(locale, translations)`. Every language works as intended (translations are set and used with `this.translate.use(locale)`), but when same process happens with Arabic translations the following error occurs:

```
SyntaxError: Expected "," or "}" but "ا" found.
    at Xt (parser.js:407)
    at parse (parser.js:1978)
    at t.value (compiler.js:39)
    at t.value (compiler.js:46)
    at t.value (compiler.js:46)
    at t.value (compiler.js:46)
    at t.value (compiler.js:46)
    at t.value (messageformat.js:385)
    at TranslateMessageFormatCompiler.compileTranslations (translate-message-format-compiler.ts:56)
    at TranslateService.setTranslation (translate.service.ts:282)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (navbar.component.ts:128)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.ts:265)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:207)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:139)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at TakeSubscriber._next (take.ts:92)
    at TakeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at ReplaySubject._subscribe (ReplaySubject.ts:80)
    at ReplaySubject._trySubscribe (Observable.ts:238)
    at ReplaySubject._trySubscribe (Subject.ts:116)
    at ReplaySubject.subscribe (Observable.ts:219)
    at TakeSubscriber.shareReplayOperation (shareReplay.ts:112)
    at AnonymousSubject.subscribe (Observable.ts:214)
    at TakeOperator.call (take.ts:72)
    at AnonymousSubject.subscribe (Observable.ts:214)
    at Object.next (navbar.component.ts:125)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.ts:265)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:207)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.ts:139)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:89)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.ts:101)
    at FilterSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.ts:162)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber._next (innerSubscribe.ts:30)
    at SimpleInnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:99)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (xhr.ts:214)
    at XMLHttpRequest.sentryWrapped (helpers.ts:85)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:27136)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:503)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1671)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1708)
```

#### Expected result

Arabic language object is compiled and used like the rest of translations.

Comment: Maybe the `ar` translation JSON is corrupt. Try downloading it and putting through linter.

Comment: Any linter you suggest? In the meantime I divided ```ar``` translations into chunks, and isolated error on one part so it is a short term fix. When I put the faulty isolated chunk into  https://jsonlint.com/ It shows a valid JSON.